# Creating a SPDT 'transistor' solution for MIDI

Tags: transistors, switches, midi

In my previous question [MIDI Both as Input or Output](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305990/using-a-midi-connector-both-as-midi-in-and-out-not-simultaneously)  the advice was to use a CD4053 to make a SPDT switch (multiples). However, I was thinking how it could be done with transistors. Not that I want to 'implement' this, but just out of curiosity if I understand the principle behind it.

I made a schema (sorry for my handwriting and no app used):

[image]

Actually only the upper part (above the orange/white line is of importance).

The idea is to have one single MIDI connector (pins 4 and 5 are used, 3 always to GND).

To select between MIDI In or Out:

- Signal from Arduino for MIDI In (enabled, HIGH) or MIDI Out (Enabled, LOW)
- When HIGH, the first and third resistor (from left to right) are getting voltage on their base, meaning a circuit is made from pin 4 and 5 from the MIDI connector, to the pin 4, MIDI In 'functionality' and pin 5, MIDI In 'functionality' (depicted as the round MIDI In circles)
- Because of the inverter, the second and fourth (from left to right) the transistors will not have voltage on their base, so will not do anything.
- When LOW, the first and third transistors will have no power on their base, while the second and third have.

Would this circuitry work? I know a CD4053 will be much easier, but it's just for trying in the future where I might need only one SPDT and a CD4053 is too much.

Comment: I didn't read or follow your earlier question. But I'm wondering. Are you forgoing galvanic isolation?

Comment: An NPN transistor is switched on only if a current flows from base to emitter, which means that the base must have a voltage 0.7V above that of the emitter, and that the current must be able to flow somewhere. Please look up how PNP transistors work, and why those are used as a high-side switch. And as jink said, you would not want to have a direct connection to your circuit on the 'wrong' side of the optocoupler.

Comment: @jonk: the opto-coupler is indeed for isolation (not sure what 'galvanic' means... However, the question is mostly about being able to use either the MIDI In 'circuits'  or MIDI Out 'circuits' depending on a pin (HIGH/LOW) from the Arduino. Later I will use a CD4053 for it, but I would like to know how to make it with transistors.

Comment: @CL: I would have to check indeed if current can flow from the base to the emitter. I will check into PNP ... and what a ' high-side'  switch means. And maybe I should indeed make sure the optocoupler does not receive any signals from the other part of the circuit (wrong side) ... A diode will probably fix that.

Comment: @CL: After reading more about low and high side switching, it is more clear (not fully) but better. I will try to change my scheme accordingly and try it.\

Comment: There are some significant problems to attend, if you are going to keep isolation while at the same time arranging for a single jack to be both OUT and IN under program control. In effect, "galvanic connection from A to B" means "there exists a path for electrons from A to B, and back again." Under no circumstances is the chassis or circuit ground of one device to be connected to the chassis or circuit ground of another. This basically means you are allowed optical (opto), magnetic (transformer), or electric fields (capacitor) only. But cable shield ties to OUT chassis, and not IN chassis.

Comment: @jonk: Yes, I understand the importance. In that case ... would it be possible - even for an output - to use an optocoupler... or even better, to put the opto coupler before the switch so it is used for both the in/out circuit ... That would result in a fully galvanic isolation.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Just focus on the cable, itself, for a moment. That's easier to think about than all the rest. The cable shield is supposed to be tied to ground or a driven virtual ground at the transmitter (OUT) side. But it is NOT supposed to be connected in any way at the receiver (IN) side. How exactly would you achieve that through opto? I think you need to consider relays. Not even the prior-suggested analog switches are acceptable, I'd say.

Comment: @jonk I never see a MIDI connection with a relay ... however, this question is about using it both as In or Out. So if I understand you right the problem is pin 3 (which is connected to GND?) ... The other 2 pins go through an opto coupler (and to GND). The MIDI Input is based on http://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=rPmmLMTW&id=8BB26900BCF5F559E38E72DE03663675C1A98FAF&thid=OIP.rPmmLMTWo8UsjDsjmsEOBQEsDR&q=midi+circuit&simid=608000064457082552&selectedIndex=0&ajaxhist=0 ... this has not pin 3 connected (but with opto coupler to GND.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers 5V and 12V coil, DPDT reed relays are fairly cheap (about 50 cents each) and small. The DIN connector alone is probably bigger. I thought about simple circuits where I didn't care about isolation and it's doable but uses a few parts -- but you don't get the isolation. If there are other devices you know about that implement what you seek without relays, then you should open them up and see what they do. My bet is that they give up the isolation. (Would not surprise me.) And perhaps you can accept that, too. I wouldn't. I'd just do it right and not look back.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers The relays do suck about half a watt, unless you work out a "switcher" circuit that utilizes their self-inductance to reduce the hold-in power required to perhaps a tenth of a watt or so. (Complex, but doable, if power consumption near a half a watt cannot be tolerated.) More expensive would be latching relays. Then it's just the momentary pulse-power required. Look up DS2E-SL2-12V, for example.

Comment: @jonk I understand it might be important ... in my case I want to use it (eventually) in a live situation with my synthesizer(s). But I already ordered CD74HC4053's ... But before they arrive I thought I already try it with transistors (and check the idea in general works). And getting more knowledge instead of using off-the-shelf ICs. 

And you now write I should use DPDT reed relays ... Which I like because alternatives are always good and you give a very good reason, so I take it into account (and foremost ... I learnt know why it is better).

Comment: @jonk ... I probably will use a 12V adapter (mostly because I don't want to get into current-problems with the +5V from MIDI). But initially I wanted to make my project for about 25 euro, I already will supersede it when I will finish it, but I think/hope those 4053's will do ok. If I need the completely galvanic isolation, at least I know now in which direction to analyze more.